# Share Link to Messenger from Web

Tags: javascript, facebook, hyperlink, facebook-messenger, facebook-messenger-bot

I know [there](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/messenger/web) is a solution for share link from web to messenger. However, I tried in chrome it work perfectly, but in messenger browser it say "Page can't be loaded". Any idea ? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you're in the messenger webview, consider implementing `beginShareFlow` with the Messenger Extensions SDK instead:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/reference/messenger-extensions-sdk/beginShareFlow